# how can I transform JSON file to Array on VUEjs?

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

how it's possible to change the object like this:

```
data() .... emojiList: [];

methods: {
  //Generated by JSON file
  //{"sweat_smile":"","laughing":"","satisfied":"","innocent":"","smiling_imp":"","wink":""};

  var emoji = emoji.emoji;

  this.emojiList = emoji;
}
```

but when I render only get the value, I'd like to make a new array with the previews, where I can set

```
{"name":"smile", "icon":""}
```

can anybody understand me?

Answer (score 2):

if your input is

```js
{"sweat_smile":"","laughing":"","satisfied":"","innocent":"","smiling_imp":"","wink":""}
```

then you can simply do:

```js
var input = { "sweat_smile":"", "laughing":"", "satisfied":"", "innocent":"", "smiling_imp":"", "wink":"" }

var output = []

Object
  .keys(input)
  .forEach(k => { 
     output.push({ name: k, icon: input[k] })
  })

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4))
```